How to pass a value from 'href' prop to 'to' prop while mocking a module
I am trying to mock Next/Link component and substitute it with react router link component.
Everything goes well except that I don't know how to pass the url from the 'href' porp of Next/Link to the 'to' prop of React Router Link.
Here is some code:
vi.mock('next/link', async () => {
  const { Link } = await vi.importActual('react-router-dom');

  return { default: Link };
});


Interesting, why would you do that?
Create your own custom Link component
import React from 'react';
import { Link as ReactRouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomLink = ({ href, ...props }) => {
  return <ReactRouterLink to={href} {...props} />;
};

export default CustomLink;

and use it as the Mock
vi.mock('next/link', async () => {
  const { default: CustomLink } = await vi.importActual('./CustomLink');
  
  return { default: CustomLink };
});

I did not test the code but I think it should work

I want to test navigation between pages in next app. Unfortunately i haven't found the way to do it. So I figured out that I try to use MemoryRouter in tests. If you have a better idea I would appreciate if you share it.

To test navigation well, you will need some sort of integration or end-to-end test. Check this example:
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/static-vs-unit-vs-integration-vs-e2e-tests#integration
(render the whole App) or use a tool like cypress/playwright.
Why can't you test with next/link?

cy is no go for me because as far as I know it's browser based and you can't integrate it with vscode. I've never tried playwright though but i assume it's the same story
